# Mockito: Getting ClassCastException from a constructor call with a mock as argument

Tags: junit, testng, mockito, powermock

I want to **Unit Test** a method with signature as

```
public oracle.sql.ARRAY  methodA(java.sql.Connection connection)
```

The connection object is mocked using

```
Mockito.mock(Connection.class)
```

and passed to methodA while testing it.

oracle.sql.ARRAY has a constructor

```
new ARRAY(oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor, Connection, Object)
```

The methodA has logic for obtaining ArrayDescriptor.
It also has logic for providing the third argument for this constructor but it provides it as an array of Objects

I am mocking these two set of logics and passing an mocked ArrayDescriptor object and a mocked Object array.
All these mocking work correctly.

So my constructor invocation is like

```
new ARRAY(arrayDescriptorMock, connectionMock, objectMock)
```

This constructor call throws an exception when executed as part of test

**java.lang.ClassCastException:$java.sql.Connection$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$2427854e 
    cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection**

I have made many attempts to mock this constructor call for avoiding this error. However, each proved futile. I am documenting my mocking code for the constructor

**Attempt1**

```
 PowerMockito.whenNew(ARRAY.class).withParameterTypes(ArrayDescriptor.class, Connection.class, Object.class)
            .withArguments(any(ArrayDescriptor.class), any(Connection.class), any(Object[].class))
            .thenReturn(expectedArray);
```

**Attempt2**

```
  PowerMockito.whenNew(ARRAY.class).withArguments(arrayDescriptorMock,connectionMock,objectArrayMock).thenReturn(expectedArray);
```

*Legend:*
arrayDescriptorMock: Mock of ArrayDescriptor

connectionMock: Mock of Connection

objectArrayMock: The mock of an object array with mocking code as

```
  Object[] structArrayMock = new Object[2];
       STRUCT obj1 = mock(STRUCT.class);
       STRUCT obj2 = mock(STRUCT.class);
       structArrayMock[0] = obj1;
       structArrayMock[1] = obj2;
```

*Notes:*
The method under test has following code which I did not mock

```
 Object[] objArray = new Object[2];
```

I am using PowerMockito, Mockito and TestNG. However, I believe this issue has nothing to do with TestNG, therefore JUNIT tag should be fine.

Kindly advise why this ClassCastException is coming and how to avoid it?

***EDIT***
I also believe that Mockito is suppose to intercept the constructor call. Meaning it should not allow execution of real constructor. It is suppose to simply return a mock object of ARRAY class. Why does that not happen? Why is it attempting Casting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beginning of answer is in the straightforward message of the exception.

```
... cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

The code shows that `oracle.sql.ARRAY` an object from the oracle driver just don't accept any `Object` (*and then mocks*) implementing the JDBC interface such as `java.sql.Connection`. This is somehow expected with any connector architecture, JDBC included as it follows JCA principles.

Why this is expected is because objects from the JCA implementation *need* to know / interact with their own objects internally. The `java.sql.Connection` interface is just the minimal usable contract that must exists for clients to this SPI (JDBC there).

So given that fact and that `oracle.sql.ARRAY` is an oracle driver type, then it is expected that this object needs an internal `oracle.sql.Connection` to behave normally. Mocking an `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection` won't even be good as `ARRAY` is probably using coupled with this type in more ways than expected, and it will ultimately lead to hellish fixture.

Ussually we, *mockists*, say : **"Don't mock types you don't own**. That's for **not** mocking `oracle.sql.Connection`. But in this test I don't see why anyone would test a code that is written by somebody else and especially a JDBC driver but if one is actually a driver developer.

If you need to test that the DAOs or the Repositories uses an `ARRAY`, then writing `Integration Tests` (with a real Oracle) would be a better fit.

---

To answer the intention, I would say definitely go for an IT. Here's why :

Actually as the tested code involves proprietary types at some point. And these types come with a driver that must connect to a real database to provide a connection to work with. I don't see an easy way to unit test,

- maybe there's some hidden types in the oracle driver that can help, but that's just a maybe and that would introduce fragility and also difficulty to refactor if later the team decides to change the database.
- or you can use a mock of the `ARRAY`, but that would break the purpose this specific test

And I must add that the first reason is the reason why I always write integration tests when my system needs to connect to another. ITs help to cover the application boundaries, including persistence. I usually call the business API of the repositories (which are DAOs with a business oriented API) and they do their job with whatever the datastore behind. Oracle or others could change the implementation of the driver, remove types, etc. And I don't have to rewrite those tests, only the actual implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I learnt a lot from it. This comment is really focusing on the last sentence. I have a method that is converting a User Defined Type (UDT) to an ARRAY instance. I need to unit test this function. How should I unit test this or should I drop the idea of unit testing this ?

Answer (score 2):

`oracle.sql.ARRAY` requires a `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection` see code from class ARRAY:

> if(!(paramArrayDescriptor.getInternalConnection().isDescriptorSharable(((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)paramConnection).physicalConnectionWithin()))){
>     throw new SQLException("Cannot construct ARRAY instance, invalid
>   connection");  }

So when you are trying to provide a `java.sql.Connection` mocked by PowerMockito, is can not casted in `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection`.

So Use this -

```
  Connection conn = PowerMockito.mock(OracleConnection.class);
```